# Hash Key Encryption for an Iphone App

Tags: ios, cocoa, encryption, hash

I am writing an Iphone app that needs to transmit data to and from a server. What is the best way to implement hash key encryption on a Iphone App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to use https/ssl? You don't have to do anything special to use https on an iPhone app.